# Return result to previous activity that is not the last activity

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

The `startActivityForResult()`and `onActivityResult` works perfect if there are only two activities are involved. But how can I handle this, if more than 2 activities exists? 
Example:
Activity A starts a new activity B, that starts activity C, that starts activity D. I want to return the result of D to activity A along with finishing activities B and C. How can I do this? Can I loop through the activity stack and finish the wanted activities or must I start a new instance of activity A?

For short: A->B->C->D has to lead back to A with the result of D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the most logical way is have the Activities take responsibility for this.

1. D returns d to C.
2. C returns d and c to B.
3. B returns b,c,d to A.

This will force you to consider the error conditions when the Activities don't happen in this cycle explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Going back closing each activity would be a good way of doing things, but if you need to jump from an activity to another and you're not using a TabHost, you could take a look at the APIDemo Reorder code

It jumps from an activity (4th) to a previous opened one (2nd) in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ReorderFour.this, ReorderTwo.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Not quit what I've searched for but I assume that I will need this someday.